# How to pass username and password for authorization header using browser

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, header, authorization

I need to access my asp.net web API using my browser. I can access this API through a rest client chrome extension by providing username and password this way.

[image]

and also able to access to API using my c# client application this way. So someone tell me how can I access to this API using web browser? how can I provide authentication details to it?

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "dGVzdDoxMjM=");
```

Comment: If the server is setup properly then accessing the URL should cause a 401/www-authenticate response which should make the browser show a username/password dialog, does that not happen?  Have you configured basic authentication or are you parsing the header manually?

Comment: @AlexK. I able to access to my API without any problem using Postman, reslet client and C# consume application. because i can provide username & password this way. but problem is when I try to consume API using my browser. because I don't now how pass username & password using browser.

Comment: @AlexK. username password dialog not pop up. I think i need to pass username password details in otherway

Comment: Then something is borked, the browser should challenge. Check you have configured basic auth correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

Comment: Yes the browser should challenge... Either that you remembered old and invalid credentials. But even then... If you want to use the browser, there are extensions that will let you add headers but that's circumventing the problem.